# Can I generate a code from an instance in the memory to re-create it later?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

Imagine I have an instance with its properties set (which is for instance loaded from the db),

and from this instance in the memory, I want to obtain a code with all the public properties set upon the current values, so that I can use this in my unit tests to re-create the instance.

Is there any trick in VS or any tool that I can make use of?

Thanks

Comment: Why not read the entity in the beginning of your test and use it? If it's serialized in your database, simply deserialize it and use it. Or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: You could serialize your instance to a JSON or XML representation, in order to store it for the future - I'm a bit confused by what your question means to be honest though.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's the public properties you wish to save, have a look at [Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx). It allows you to stream an object to a binary format or to XML, and retrieve it later. The stream can be a memory stream or a file, depending on how long you wish to save it. Here is the code from that MSDN page showing how to save an object to an XML file and read it back later:

```
public class Book
{
    public String title;
}       

public static void WriteXML()       
{
    // First write something so that there is something to read ...
    var b = new Book { title = "Serialization Overview" };
    var writer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Book));
    var wfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\SerializationOverview.xml");
    writer.Serialize(wfile, b);
    wfile.Close();
}

public void ReadXML()
    // Now we can read the serialized book ...
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer reader = 
        new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Book));
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(
        @"c:\temp\SerializationOverview.xml");
    Book overview =  (Book)reader.Deserialize(file);
    file.Close();

    Console.WriteLine(overview.title);    
}
```

That said, I am not sure Serialization is the best option if you want to use it to re-create objects in unit tests. Usually, you would create a separate (possibly in-memory) database, or mock out the database interface to return hard-coded objects. For example, suppose you have the following production code:

```
public interface IDataAccess {
   User GetUserById(int userId);
}

public class SqlServerDataAccess : IDataAccess { 
   public User GetUserById(int userId) {
     // ... connect to database and retrieve user
   }
}
```

Then for your unit test you may write an implementation

```
public class MockDataAccess : IDataAccess { 
   public User GetUserById(int userId) {
     return new User() { 
       Name = "pencilCake", ...
     }
   }
}
```

and use that for your unit tests. There are even frameworks like Moq and Rhino that will allow you to create such interfaces "on-the-fly", allowing you to return a specific hardcoded object for every test method.